# matplotlib.pyplot imshow() now shows a solid blue colour, no longer the colour rendering?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Further to my previous, helpfully addressed, question here
[How to centre the origin in the centre of an imshow() plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124192/how-to-centre-the-origin-in-the-centre-of-an-imshow-plot)
after some fiddling about with the some parameters, spyder now consistently shows a blank blue output. It is baffling!! 
I've forced the dtype to be uint8 (I read this on a related question that this may be the cause) but to no avail.

**EDIT:** (Thanks to the rapid responses) here is the relevant code (from a larger program for modelling diffraction through a square aperture):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def expo(x,y,z,xp,yp,k):
    """
    Function of the integrand in Eq. 5
    """
    return np.exp((1j*k/(2*z))*(((x-xp)**2) + ((y-yp)**2))) 

def square_2dsimpson_eval(a,b,n):
    simp_eval = np.zeros((n+1,n+1))
    deltap = (b-a)/n
    xp = 0
    yp = 0
    w = np.zeros((n+1,n+1))
    x=0
    y=0
    for h in range(n+1):    #the first two for loops produce the 2d Simpson matrix of coeffecients
        if h == 0 or h==n:
            w[0,h] = 1

        elif h%2 != 0:
            w[0,h]=4

        elif h%2 == 0:
            w[0,h]=2

    for g in range(n+1):
        if g ==0 or g==n:
            w[g,0]=1

        elif g%2 != 0:
            w[g,0]=4             

        elif g%2 == 0:
            w[g,0]=2

    for h in range(1,n+1):
        for g in range(1,n+1):
            w[h,g]=w[0,h]*w[g,0]

    for h in range(0,n+1):
        xp = h*deltap
        for g in range(0,n+1):
            yp = g*deltap
            simp_eval[h,g] = expo(x,y,z,xp,yp,k) #the integrand

    return (k/(2*np.pi*z))*((deltap**2)/9)*(np.sum(simp_eval*w))

n = 3.3

        #this loop checks that user's N is even as required for Simpson's rule
        while n % 2 != 0:
            n = int(input("Type an even N value: "))
            if n % 2 == 0:
                break
            else:
                print("n must be even you noob!")
        lam=float(input("Type light wavelength in mm: "))
        k=(2*np.pi)/lam
        z=float(input("Type screen distance, z in mm: "))
        rho=float(input("Type rho in mm: "))

        delta = 2/n
        intensity = np.zeros((n+1,n+1),dtype='uint8')
        for i in range(n+1):
            x=-1+(i*delta)
            for j in range(n+1):
                y =-1+(j*delta)
                intensity[i,j] = (abs(square_2dsimpson_eval(-rho/2,rho/2,n)))**2  
        print(intensity.dtype)
        plt.imshow(intensity)
        plt.show()
```

The plot has gone from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your actual data look like? Can you provide code to generate your result. It is helpful to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just edited my question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Without</strike> *Even* knowing the code that produces either image, I can only say that the second image seems to be a cutout of the first image in a region where there is no data or data is close to or equal the minimum value.

[image]